# How to specify in the addToSet operator the key to be used to determine whether the document to be added is a duplicate or not?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to use the addToSet operator by adding documents. As per the mongo documentation;

Value to Add is a Document:

If the value is a document, MongoDB determines that the document is a duplicate if an existing document in the array matches the to-be added document exactly; i.e the existing document has the exact same fields values and the fields are in the same order. **As such, field order matters and you cannot specify that MongoDB compare only a subset of the fields in the document to determine whether the document is a duplicate of a
n existing array element**

Is there a workaround for this?. The issue is that the documents to compare have two fields, filename and the file represented in base64. The file comparison will be too heavy as the base64 strings are way too large. Will mongoDB be efficient at doing this? Is there a way we can tell addToSet to just compare based on filename? Otherwise should I just fetch the dataset and do the compare in the server program?

Answer (score -1):

You are likely to have other issues with this schema if you bundle metadata and file contents in the same (sub)document.

But, to given an answer commensurate with the information provided, you can use https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/ to construct new arrays in expressions and you can do that conditionally with https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/. You need to perform the query under $cond then construct the new array in one of the branches, otherwise use the existing array. It's a fair amount of typing but should achieve what you are asking to do.